# mean and sd in R (normal distribution)

Tags: r, random, mean

In an exercise for beginner in R, the asked question is to generate a random sample of size 100 with the mean = 10 and sd = 3, so for this I used the rnorm(n=100,mean=10,sd=3). But, when I try to generate the mean and the sd of the generated sample I obtain a mean = 9.998 and sd = 3.478. My question is: Why there is a difference between the two mean and the two sd (a silly question I know) ?

Have a nice day

Comment: stats 101: because it's a sample from a population. Would you have measured the population you would have obtained the exact values but a sample is never exactly like the population it is from. But the larger the sample, the closer you get.

Comment: As an exercise, I would recommend doing this for ever increasing sample sizes and plot how the "sample mean and sd" approaches the "population mean and sd". This will help anchor the concept, which frankly many people never really get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to illustrate what was mentioned already mentioned in the comments.
For increasing sample sizes I calculated 10 times the mean of a random sample. What you can see is that the sd in the sample means is decreasing with increasing sample size. This corresponds to the length of the red lines.  In turn the expected error in sample mean is also decreasing.
What you can also observe is that the maximal outlier of the means (the black lines) are coming closer to the true mean.
  Also the mean of the mean comes closer to the true mean, however, this is imho kind of boring.

Hope this helps

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
length=20

samples <- (1:length)*40

  values<-unlist(lapply(samples,
                 function(x){
                   lapply(1:10,
                         function(z) {
                           mean(rnorm(x,mean=10,sd=3))
                           }
                         )
                   }
                 ))

counts <- sort(rep(samples,10))  
points <- data.frame(counts=unlist(counts),values=(unlist(values)))
ggplot(points,aes(counts,values))+geom_point()+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,color="red",size=2,fun.ymin = function(x){mean(x)-sd(x)}, fun.ymax = function(x){mean(x+sd(x))})+
 stat_summary(fun.y=max,geom="line")+
 stat_summary(fun.y=min,geom="line")
```